# WPF Charting ColumnSeries with CategoryAxis, margin between the Columns

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpftoolkit

I have a column chart which is grouped with a CategoryAxis.

My problem is that when the columns are grouped together there is no spacing/margin between the columns.

I have tried to apply a style with margin on the DataPoint, but the only this that does is to move all the columns but not applying a margin on each column.

See image:

[image]
Styling code:

```
<Charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
 <Style TargetType="Charting:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <Setter
      Property="MaxWidth"
      Value="5" />
    <Setter
     Property="MaxWidth"
     Value="5" />
  </Style>
</Charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

Comment: maybe the problem is related to fixed space **between** not **within** each group. have you tried adding a HorizontalScrollBar or reducing the number of groups?

Comment: prolly silly question but have you tried padding?

Answer (score 1):

I was approaching this problem the wrong way, the actually issue was that all the bars are the same data series. When I split up each bar to its own data series I got the desired result.